# How do I identify most related parameters in statistical modeling

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, probability, recommendation-engine

I have data about car mechanic company which allow mechanics to apply for there garrage on freelance basis.

I have previous mechanic job history and based on this historical data, I want to recommend best possible location to mechanics so that he can get good job and company gets maximum acceptance.

I manually checked various parameters like location_ID, lang, lat of the job location, mechanic_Exp_years, open_position, mechanic_specialization etc.

Also tried to see relation using chart like this

https://imgur.com/a/jxmTXty

I am adding link because can not upload image due to less then 10 point

Is there any standards technique available which can statistically says that out of this 100 parameters this paramteres are good to be considered for prediction/training?

Any reference link or library much appreciated. I did checked many articles but no luck

Comment: This is an interesting question, but more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to do that. If you're using python, I would recommend scikit-learn's `FeatureSelection` module. There are many methods listed, but my pick would be [Recursive Feature Elimination](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE) or short RFE. The RFE works by recursively removing attributes and building a model on those attributes that remain. It uses the model accuracy to identify which attributes (and combination of attributes) contribute the most to predicting the target attribute.

Other then that, you can also try to use PCA (Principal Component Analysis) to reduce your features to only useful ones that bring some information to your model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate. I can not upvote being new contributor and less points. Also disappointed to see downvote.